# How to See Headers after Call Other API with NodeJS Loopback?

Tags: node.js, httpresponse, loopbackjs, loopback

After send a request, can't see the headers from response

1. In the controller I have the method to send the request:

```
     @get('/getToken')
              async getToken(): Promise<any> {
                return await this.s4hanapurreqService.getToken(); <- Response Ok
              }
```

2. This method call another in the services file:

Interface:

```
    export interface S4hanapurreqService {
    getToken(): Promise<any>;
    }
```

3. This interface S4hanapurreqService has the communications with the datasource

```
      async value(): Promise<S4hanapurreqService> {
        return getService(this.dataSource);
      }
```

DataSource:

```
     "operations": [
        {
          "template": {
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "https://<some url>",
            "headers": {
              "x-csrf-token": "fetch"
            }
          },
          "functions": {
            "getToken": [] <-- this is my controller method
          }
        }
```

All works fine, because I get the response:

Controller:

```
    @get('/getToken')
      async getToken(): Promise<any> {
        return await this.s4hanapurreqService.getToken(); <- Response Ok
      }
```

Json Response:

```
    {
        "d": {
            "EntitySets": [
                 ... Data  ...
            ]
        }
    }
```

but when I debugging I see that I only have this and the header does not appear like the status ,200,201 , etc

I can't use this beacuse fail:

```
    var token = response.headers['x-crsf-token'];
```

Which is the correct code for get the header from my response?

Regards.

Comment: Hi. Please consider be more concise and more clear. Since there is a lot of short code extracts and sentences, it's hard to see what is your problem. response.get('key') gives will give you a header.

Comment: this is exactly my problem, get the key header, I try with response.('x-csrf-token')
and the console response me 

"Unhandled error in GET /getToken: 500 TypeError: response.get is not a function"

Comment: I just give you the answer. res.get('key') will return the key header.

Comment: The error is elsewhere, but your question is a mess not understandable. Be more clear or debug it step by step. Your response variable is not an express response.

Comment: already,, I need modify the node modules, loopback-connector-rest in rest-builder.js in the method:

RequestBuilder.prototype.invoke = function(parameters, cb) , when do the return changue body for response and then I has access to the headers and body in the same property

with this
res.headers['x-csrf-token'];

thanks, so much

Regards

Comment: You're welcome. Consider give points to answers that helped you ;)